# Angular - Uncaught Error: AdminLTE requires jQuery at adminlte.min.js:14

Tags: angular, adminlte

I am working a project using AdminLTE theme in Angular 7. When I served the App, I got this error on the console:

> Uncaught Error: AdminLTE requires jQuery
>       at adminlte.min.js:14

This is the line 14 of adminlte.min.js

```js
if("undefined"==typeof jQuery)throw new Error("AdminLTE requires jQuery");+function(a){"use strict";function b(b){return this.each(function(){var e=a(this),g=e.data(c);if(!g){var h=a.extend({},d,e.data(),"object"==typeof b&&b);e.data(c,g=new f(e,h))}if("string"==typeof g){if(void 0===g[b])throw new
```

> demo.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at demo.js:7

This is the line 7 of demo.js

> $(function () {

I tried to read the documentation, and found out that I was doing the right thing. However, when I commented on the demo.js reference the error was not there. But I need this javascript.
Please how do I get it resolved.

Comment: You can import Jquery as mentioned in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstall the AdminLTE-2.4.15 theme. the re-install to a lower version AdminLTE-2.4.8.  Then, problem solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure jQuery is imported *and* jQuery is imported before adminlte.min.js *and* that the initialization of AdminLTE functions is in `$(function () { /** Initialize AdminLTE functions **/}`.

`$(function () {}` is basically a way of saying "Yup I have loaded jQuery functions, now let's execute `$.` whatever is required from AdminLTE"